# How to rotate the image from original and back to it?

Tags: ios, cgaffinetransform

I have try to rotate the image by using `CGAffineTransformMakeRotation` and `CGAffineTransformRotate`. I want to rotate the image from it's original and clockwise to the original again(like degree 0 to 360). I need to rotate image like a CD on the player. I did something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.1];  
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -180);
ImageView.transform = transform;

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

it just spin to the degree 180, and if I change it to -300 it will rotate counterclockwise (that not what I need).

Answer (score 0):

the angle of rotation is given better by `atan2()` suppose A and B are two points on the centerline to which your image is to be rotated then the angle of rotation is

`0-atan2((b.x - a.x) ,(b.y -a.y))`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-(void)startAnimationWithRevolutions:(float)revPerSecond forTime:(float)time
{
    spinWheel.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    float totalRevolutions = revPerSecond * time;
    [CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:time] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];

    CABasicAnimation* spinAnimation = [CABasicAnimation
                                       animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
    CGAffineTransform transform = spinWheel.transform;
    float fromAngle = atan2(transform.b, transform.a);
    float toAngle = fromAngle + (totalRevolutions*4*M_PI);
    spinAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:fromAngle];
    spinAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:toAngle];
    spinAnimation.repeatCount = 0;
    spinAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    spinAnimation.delegate = self;
    spinAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:
                                    kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut];
    [spinWheel.layer addAnimation:spinAnimation forKey:@"spinAnimation"];
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -180);
    ImageView.transform = transform;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,0);
    ImageView.transform = transform;
}];
```